# Enable user interaction on the table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interaction

So I have a tableView with navigation controller. And the data loads from url. So when row is selected another table view appears while the data is loading the back button on the navigation bar is is disabled and scrolling and whole user interaction. What I need, is to enable the back button in navigation controller even if data is bot loaded yet. Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read Threading programming [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html).